# Postback in JSF

Tags: jsf, postback, oracle-adf

I've created a very simple JSF to test what is exactly a postback. The JSP contains a outputtext to print the 'adfFacesContext.postback' expression, and a button to do a submit.

```
<f:view>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"/>
  <title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
  <af:form>        
    <h:outputText value="#{adfFacesContext.postback}" />
    <h:commandButton value="SUBMIT" action="ok"/>
  </af:form>
  </body>
</html>
</f:view>
```

I've created in faces-config.xml a navigation rule:

```
  <navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/test.jsp</from-view-id>    
    <navigation-case>
      <from-outcome>ok</from-outcome>
      <to-view-id>/test.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>    
  </navigation-rule>
```

The first time the page is loaded, "adfFacesContext.postback" expression is evaluated to false, so everything right.

But when I press the button, "adfFacesContext.postback" expression is evaluated to false again.

Why?

I've observed that if I remove the navitation rule from faces-config.xml, when I press the button, "adfFacesContext.postback" expression is evaluated to true.

Why I've to remove the navigation rule to get the right results?

Comment: Are you using ADF-JSF or standard JSF? ADF-JSF has a different lifecycle than standard JSF.

Comment: I'm using ADF 10g that has been built over JSF 1. The lifecycle is different, but because ADF extends the number of phases. The standard JSF phases are the same.